# How to detect who is move white or black in python-chess library?

Tags: python, chess, python-chess

I am created some chess program and want to detect who have move white or black. Which objects stores information which pieces will move **Board**, **GameNode**?

```
import chess.pgn
import chess.uci

# ??? Board().is_white_move()?
# ??? GameNode.is_white_move()?
```

I analysed code but not found good explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you are looking at [python-chess](https://github.com/niklasf/python-chess).

There's a [turn](http://python-chess.readthedocs.org/en/latest/core.html?highlight=is_white_move#Board.turn) attribute of the Board instance.